# In Illustrator's Export for Screens, how do I specify exact height in px – or see what the actual pixel dimensions are?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

- I'm using Adobe Illustrator 27.2 on Windows. This is the current version as of February 2023 on Creative Cloud.
- I have an Illustrator document of a company logo originally intended for print use: the artboard dimensions are in Inches and it uses CMYK color (and the DPI is set really high, so the artboard's pixel dimensions are in thousands of pixels).
- I'm wanting to export it as a 400 px **tall** transparent PNG file – preserving aspect ratio.
- Using *File → Export → Export for Screens,* the formats list lets me specify the usual scale-multipliers (1x, 3x) but does not *seem* to let me specify exact dimensions for height or width:

  [image: Screenshot of a poorly designed software UI]

  - The drop-down options for *Width* and *Height* both enter “100px” into the box, and on export this seems to control the **width** of the image, not the height.

    - This is a bug, surely? (And where is it getting “100px” from?)

My questions:

- How do I tell Illustrator I want a one-off 32-bit transparent PNG export that's 400px tall and have Illustrator calculate the width for me?
- And how can I see, in advance, what the actual pixel dimensions of each output format/scale would be?

  - For example, if I choose a "3x PNG", how can I be sure it isn't going to generate a 100,000 px × 50,000 px output image (due to the artboard's high DPI)?

Unfortunately I can't use the older (and arguably better...) *Save for Web* dialog because the menu option is disabled for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you started a new file at 8.5 x 11" and turned on rulers, then select Export > Export as... and select jpg, then it will ask what dpi you want it to be. If you say 300dpi and the image on the 8.5 x 11" size sheet is 8 x 10", then you'll get a jpg image that is 2400px x 3000px. You can choose "Other" and calculate what would get it closer to your final size.

In Photoshop you can open and resize more accurately.

Comment: When I use "Export as..." it doesn't let me set _any_ pixel dimensions, only the PPI resolution, which is no better than _Export for Screens_; furthermore the _Export As_ dialog doesn't tell you what the actual output dimensions will be either. I shouldn't need to use a separate spreadsheet and calculator to figure out the conversions. _le sigh_

Comment: If you know your actual image is 1 inch square, and you export it as 300dpi, you should expect it to be 300px square, right? Try it and open in it Photoshop to check its width in pixels.